# Show form fields conditionally based on user radio input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have a little problem, because i am beginner in JS. 
I have 4 entries. Another entry will open for each. 
At a and b, it works. I mean, if I have 2 inputs, I know how to do it. When I open the aQuestion entry it opens. and at b it is the same.
The problem is at c and d, ie if I have more than 2 inputs. I tried, but it doesn't work...

Thanks a lot!

```js
function displayQuestion(answer) { 

  document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";

  if (answer == "a") { // hide the div that is not selected

    document.getElementById('bQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }
   if (answer == "b") {

    document.getElementById('aQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }
    
   if (answer == "c") {

    document.getElementById('dQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }

  if (answer == "d") {

    document.getElementById('cQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }


}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: left;">
  <h2>Tip taxa*</h2><br><br>

  <!--Below is html code. -->
<label>
 <!--First input A -->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="a" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="a" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />A</label>
  <label><br>
   <!--Second input B-->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="b" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="b" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />B</label><br>
<!--3 input C -->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="c" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="c" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />C</label><br>
<!--4 input D-->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="d" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="d" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />D</label><br>
   



</div>

<!--A new one will open for each of the above inputs-->

<!--For a opne  aQuestion -->
  <div id="aQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>
    <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="2.00" readonly="">
  </div>
<!--For b opne  bQuestion -->
  <div id="bQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>

   <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="20.00" readonly="">
  </div>
<!--For c opne  cQuestion -->
  <div id="cQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>

   <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="200.00" readonly="">
  </div>
<!--For d opne  dQuestion -->
   <div id="dQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>

   <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="2000.00" readonly="">
  </div>
```

Comment: did you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having 4 input fields for display answer for each option, keep one single input and set the answer to that input field based in the selection. like follows.

```js
function displayQuestion(answer) { 

  document.getElementById('answer').value = answer;
  document.getElementById('aQuestion').style.display='block';

}
```

```html
<h2>Tip taxa*</h2><br><br>

  <!--Below is html code. -->
<label>
 <!--First input A -->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="a" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="2.00" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />A</label>
  <label><br>
   <!--Second input B-->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="b" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="20.00" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />B</label><br>
<!--3 input C -->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="c" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="200.00" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />C</label><br>
<!--4 input D-->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="d" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="2000.00" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />D</label><br>
   


</div>


  <div id="aQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>
    <input type="text" id="answer" name="suma" readonly="true">
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: In the meantime, I tried another way. But yours is much better and simpler. Thank you very much, sit! All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the opening label tag on C and D

By the way, you shouldn't have multiple same id's. Id's should stay unique. :)

```js
function displayQuestion(answer) { 

  document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";

  if (answer == "a") { // hide the div that is not selected

    document.getElementById('bQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }
   if (answer == "b") {

    document.getElementById('aQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }
    
   if (answer == "c") {

    document.getElementById('dQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }

  if (answer == "d") {

    document.getElementById('cQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }


}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: left;">
  <h2>Tip taxa*</h2><br><br>

  <!--Below is html code. -->
<label>
 <!--First input A -->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="a" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="a" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />A</label>
  <label><br>
   <!--Second input B-->
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="b" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="b" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />B</label><br>
<!--3 input C -->
<label>
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="c" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="c" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />C</label><br>
<!--4 input D-->
<label>
    <input class="radioo" type="radio" id="d" name="yesOrNo" required="" value="d" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />D</label><br>
   



</div>

<!--A new one will open for each of the above inputs-->

<!--For a opne  aQuestion -->
  <div id="aQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>
    <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="2.00" readonly="">
  </div>
<!--For b opne  bQuestion -->
  <div id="bQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>

   <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="20.00" readonly="">
  </div>
<!--For c opne  cQuestion -->
  <div id="cQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>

   <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="200.00" readonly="">
  </div>
<!--For d opne  dQuestion -->
   <div id="dQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>

   <input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="2000.00" readonly="">
  </div>
```

Comment: The id s is unique for each one. a, b, c and d. Or i don't understand good?

Comment: I mean on the inputs they all have an id of "suma"